# str_replace php for links

Tags: php, string, replace

Looking to do a replace for google index my links without spaces, commas, and another characters

my curent code

```
<a href="report-<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", $db['Subject'])?>-<?=$db['id']?>" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>
```

I'm looking to make it for any characters like $, #, &, ! ; not only for spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$replace=str_replace(array(" ","\$","#","&","!",";"),'-',$db['Subject']);
echo "<a href='report-{$replace}-{$db['id']}' class='read-more-button'>Read More</a>";
?>
```

This creates a variables $replace with a str_replace'ing anything in the array with a hyphen

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use to create slugs

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', trim($string))))));
```

Answer (score 0):

the str_replace function allows you to use an array for the replaces.  Like this:

1st create an array of character you want to replace:

```
$replace = array(" ", "-", "_", "#", "+", "*");
```

then in your str_replace you give it the array name:

```
$originalString = '<a href="http://www.somewhere.co.uk">My Link</a>';

$newString = str_replace($replace, "", $originalString);
```

$newString will have removed each item that is in the $replace array.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an `array` to the `str_replace` function like so:

```
$strip = array('%','$','#','&','!'); 
<a href="report-<?=str_replace($strip, '-', $db['Subject'])?>-<?=$db['id']?>" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>
```

However, to create URL's i use this:

```
<?php
    function stripChars($str)
    {
        $bads    =    array(".","+"," ","#","?","!","&" ,"%",":","–","/","\\","'","\"","”","“",",","£","’");
        $goods   =    array("","-","-","-","" ,"" ,"and","" ,"" ,"" ,"","","","","","","","","","");
        $str    =    str_replace($bads,$goods,$str);
        return strtolower($str);
    }
?>
    <a href="<?=stripChars('report ' . $db['Subject'] . ' ' . $db['id'])?>" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to askingbox author:

```
$f = 'fi?le.txt';

$f = str_replace(array('$', '#',' &', '!', '\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|'),' ',$f);

echo $f; // 'fi le.txt'
```

### Use:

```
function make_safe($str){
return  str_replace(array('$', '#',' &', '!', '\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|'),' ',$str);
}

<a href="report-<?php echo make_safe($db['Subject'])?>-<?=$db['id']?>" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>
```